# Configurar carpeta de un servidor con contraseña para acceder luego desde una url

Tags: webservice, servidor

Lo que quiero hacer es que no se pueda acceder a una carpeta en la que guardo documentos, solo si se tiene usuario y contraseña:

- ¿Cómo puedo poner una contraseña en una carpeta de un servidor?
- ¿Cómo puedo acceder luego a dicha carpeta desde una URL?
- ¿Dónde tendría que poner la contraseña en la URL?

Es un servidor Linux con Apache, y accedo desde una URL para obtener un XML que muestro en una web.

Comment: que tecnologias y ambiente estas utilizando? o sea el servidor es windows, el webservice es asp.net o alguna otra tecnologia? el servidor esta local en la red o en un hosting ?

Comment: Es un servidor en apache con linux @LeandroTuttini

Comment: la idea es acceder desde una pagina web en el browser o puedes evaluar algun otro protocolo? porque por el planteo que realizas un servicio FTP resolveria el problema

Comment: Accedo desde una url para obtener un xml que muestro en una web @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `.htaccess` junto a `.htpasswd`.

El fichero `.htpasswd` contendrá una lista con los usuarios y las contraseñas. Puedes generarlo online en [sitios como éste](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/), o en la misma línea de comandos de linux ejecutando el siguiente comando en el sitio en donde quieras tener el fichero `.htpasswd`:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd [nombre-del-usuario]

...aquí aparecerá algo pidiendo la contraseña para ese usuario...
```

> OJO: El `-c` es para crear el fichero .htpasswd y sólo debes usarlo la primera vez o te borrará los usuarios ya existentes.

Una vez tienes el fichero `.htpasswd` en tu servidor, lo que te queda por hacer es añadir un fichero `.htaccess` al directorio que quieres que esté protegido por contraseña y que apunte al fichero `.htpasswd` que acabas de crear.

El contenido de `.htaccess` sería algo como esto:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Pon aquí el mensaje que quieres que muestre la venta que pide la contraeña"
AuthUserFile <ruta-a-tu-fichero-creado-con-htpasswd>
Require valid-user
```

Cuando accedas a la URL de ese directorio o alguno de los ficheros que contenga, el navegador abrirá una ventana para que introduzcas el usuario y contraseña y puedas acceder a su contenido.